# MERGE query for Array of Struct in Big Query

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery

I have a target table with the following columns :-

```
super_user STRUCT<id INT64, login STRING, full_name STRING, email STRING, preferred_name STRING>,
admin ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, login STRING, full_name STRING, email STRING, preferred_name STRING>>,
user ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, login STRING, full_name STRING, email STRING, preferred_name STRING>>,
```

From a source table with similar schema, I want to perform MERGE operation on these columns' subfields. Using "=" is not an option since these columns are Array of struct. I tried doing the UNNEST way but I am not able to form the part where I could unnest the target table's columns and compare. I would really appreciate some help on writing this merge query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not take the time and normalize your structure

Comment: The schema is already decided and unfortunately there's no scope for changes there.

Comment: then unnest your array and use that see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays?hl=de

Answer (score 0):

use the merge statement with when matched clause and then update the subfields using the set clause

```
MERGE target_table AS target
USING source_table AS source
ON target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    target.super_user = source.super_user,
    target.admin = source.admin,
    target.user = source.user;
```

Comment: In my usecase, I have to perform insert if any subfield of super_user or admin array or user array is changed. So that needs to go in the ON condition, but in BQ "=" is not defined to check equality of two array or array of struct. That's where my doubt is. I know I need to unnest the fields but that's the difficult part where I need help.